# Is it okay to use relative error on a set of measurements rather than an absolute error?

Tags: error, measurement-error

As far as I've learned, if you have a set of measurements and the differences between the average of those measurements and the individual measurements aren't always smaller than the absolute error of your individual measurements, you have non-reproducible errors and need to apply statistics to find a standard deviation etc.

I was wondering whether it would be okay to pick a certain constant relative error that applies to all your measurements rather than an absolute one.

Here's an example:

I have a bunch of time measurements and the same absolute error for each of them. If the time is short (3-9 seconds) the results are considered reproducible by my above definition. If the time is longer than that, the results vary too much and become non-reproducible. Instead of using the aforementioned absolute error I could pick a relative error that works for all results so that I can process all the results in the same way.

I'm applying this to 3 measurements of upwards and downwards velocity of oildrops in a magnetic field (Millikan) for 20 different drops. Out of these times I'll determine the velocity and eventually the charge and size of the particles. The final result I want to get is the elementary charge of an electron.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer your question, or even point you in the right direction, until you finish the question. Once you have the data, what will you do with it? What questions are you using statistics to answer?

Comment: I've added more info to the question. In short I eventually need to get the elementary charge of an electron out of this.